# How to make ng-repeat content inside unordered list (ul) scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a list of messages in an unordered list. I'd like to give the list a percentage height and have it be scrollable. I tried adding a height attribute to the ul but it didnt do anything. 

 JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3hq9ay42/1/

**view**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Chat</h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <!-- List all messages -->
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 chat-message" ng-repeat="message in chat_messages">
                <span ng-bind="message"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.chat_messages = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the height to whatever you want using **CSS**, but it must be shorter than the list default height otherwise you won't be able to see the scroller.

```
ul.list-unstyled {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned adding height didnt do anything

Comment: why does it only work after adding overflow-y: auto. Shouldnt height still do something.

Comment: To make it work with percentages you have to set height to all of the parents include the body